# If you are standing on the shore and it is high tide, what are the two possible locations for the moon relative to where you are?

Tags: the-moon, tidal-forces

Science Class If you are standing on the shore and it is high tide,

Comment: You need a new science teacher, and maybe even a new science textbook. Your science teacher wants you to answer with overhead or underfoot. That is wrong. See [High tides do not coincide with the location of the moon](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/moon-tide.html). Also see [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/121858/52112) to [Does Earth really have two high-tide bulges on opposite sides?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/121830)